# How to reload background UITableView from Modal View

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to show an information which is in Core Data, on UITableViewCell.
I could get the information, but the information wasn't shown on UITableViewCell.

When I set the information on CoreData, I use Modal View then.

I tried to use `UITableView.reload()` but I couldn't show the information on UITableViewCell.

Please let me know how to show the information when I back from modal view.

This class is about showing the information on UItableView.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol FriendListTableViewDelegate {
    func reloadTable()
}

class FriendListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, FriendListTableViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var friendListTableView: UITableView!

    var friends:[FriendBasicInfo] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getData()
    }
    // Disable to effect the reload
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        reloadTable()
    }

    // fetch the information from CoreData
    func getData() {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do {
            friends = try context.fetch(FriendBasicInfo.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }

    func reloadTable() {
        friendListTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return friends.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let friendCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FriendListCell") as! FriendListTableViewCell

        let friendName = friendCell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
        let friendImage = friendCell.viewWithTag(2) as? UIImageView

        friendName?.text = friends[indexPath.row].name
        friendImage?.image = friends[indexPath.row].photo?.toImage()

        return friendCell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }

}
```

This class is to get the information from CoreData

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip
import Eureka
import CoreData
import ImageRow

class InputFriendInforViewController: FormViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {

    var itemInfo: IndicatorInfo = "Info"
    var friendPhoto: UIImage?
    var friendName: String = ""
    var friendBirthday: Date?
    var friendGender: String = ""
    var friendListTableViewDelegate: FriendListTableViewDelegate!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       form +++

        Section("Friend Information")
            <<< ImageRow(){
                $0.title = "Image"
                $0.sourceTypes = [.PhotoLibrary, .SavedPhotosAlbum, .Camera]
                $0.value = UIImage(named: "noImage")
                $0.onChange { [unowned self] row in
                                self.friendPhoto = row.value!
                            }
            }
            <<< TextRow(){ row in
                row.title = "Name"
                row.placeholder = "Enter Name here"
            }.onChange { name in
                self.friendName = name.value!
            }
            <<< DateRow(){ row in
                row.title = "Birthday"
                row.value = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)
            }.onChange {date in
                self.friendBirthday = date.value!
            }
        <<< PushRow<String>(){row in
                row.title = "Gender"
                row.options = ["Male","Female","Other"]
            }.onChange {gender in
                self.friendGender = gender.value!
            }

        +++ Section()
            <<< ButtonRow() {
                $0.title = "SAVE"
            }.onCellSelection {_, _ in
                self.saveInfo()
            }
    }

    // MARK: - IndicatorInfoProvider

    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
        return itemInfo
    }

    // save friend Info for Core Data
    func saveInfo (){

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let friendEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "FriendBasicInfo", in: managedContext)!

        let friendInfo = NSManagedObject(entity: friendEntity, insertInto: managedContext)

        // make unique user ID
        let friendUid = NSUUID().uuidString

        // Image Data UIImage to png Data
        let pngImage = self.friendPhoto?.toPNGData()

        friendInfo.setValue(friendUid, forKey: "userID")
        friendInfo.setValue(pngImage, forKey: "photo")
        friendInfo.setValue(self.friendName, forKey: "name")
        friendInfo.setValue(self.friendBirthday, forKey: "birthday")
        friendInfo.setValue(self.friendGender, forKey: "gender")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

This class is about UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class FriendListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var sampleImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var sampleLabel:UILabel!
}
```

V/r,

Answer (score 2):

As you are using an extra data source array just reloading the table view doesn't consider the new inserted item.

There are a few options

1. Use `NSFetchedResultsController`. It updates the UI automatically when the context was saved.
2. On dismiss insert the new item into the data source array and a new row into the table view.
3. Observe `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and insert the item as described in 2.
4. Refetch the entire data and reload the table view.

The options are in order of efficiency. Version 1 is the most efficient one.

Side note:

`viewWithTag` is horribly old-fashioned. You got outlets, use them for example

```
cell.sampleLabel!.text = friends[indexPath.row].name
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. I am trying to do by Version 1. I'm checking on Apple reference. But I don't make any sense on Apple reference. ```let context = <#Managed object context#>```  Could you tell me any information, or advice?https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: `<#Managed object context#>` is a placeholder for the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance. Please look at [this tutorial](https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3) (also the subsequent parts)

Answer (score 0):

Your FriendListViewController TableView will reflect any updates to any FriendBasicInfo Entity which was fetched within getData() method. To present a new inserted FriendBasicInfo Entities to the database you have to execute a new fetch with getData() method.

**Solution:**

```
func reloadTable() {
    getData()
    friendListTableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Alternative solution**

Advanced monitoring of a fetched entities can be done with [NSFetchedResultsController](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=nsfetchedresultscontroller&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) Delegate, this controller will automatically update the FriendListViewController tableview for any updated, inserted or deleted entities.